# Chrome Extension content scripts not firing code

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to grab the URL for every new page that is visited by the user. I found a SO answer that said to use `content_scripts` so I put this in my manifest:

```
"permissions": [
  "tabs"
],
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
  "js": ["js/background.js"]
}
```

I also tried matches like this:

```
"matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
```

And this is my `background.js` file:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    alert(changeInfo.url);
});

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(activeInfo) {
  // how to fetch tab url using activeInfo.tabid
  chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId, function(tab){
     console.log(tab.url);
  });
});

alert("BACON");
```

Nothing gets fired off after reloading the extension and then opening up new tabs and going to various websites. Could someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you read the [overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [content scripts documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts):

> Content scripts have some limitations. They cannot use chrome.* APIs, with the exception of:
>
> - extension (getURL, inIncognitoContext, lastError, onRequest, sendRequest)
> - i18n
> - runtime (connect, getManifest, getURL, id, onConnect, onMessage, sendMessage)
> - storage

**Solution: in order to access `chrome.tabs` API you should use a background page script.**

Also note that according to [chrome.tabs API documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs):

> You can use most `chrome.tabs` methods and events without declaring any permissions in the extension's manifest file. However, **if you require access to the url, title, or favIconUrl properties of `tabs.Tab`, you must declare the `"tabs"` permission** in the manifest

**manifest.json**

```
...
"permissions": [
  "tabs"
],
"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
...
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.status==='loading' && changeInfo.url) {
    alert(changeInfo.url);
  }
});
```

Comment: Also just for further clarification, I already had the "tabs" permission in the manifest. What fixed the problem was actually not using a content_script. Declaring a background script in the manifest was actually what solved the issue.

Comment: @Sloganho, indeed, I've missed that in the question. You may want to read the [extension architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) (arguably about half of the questions are asked because people didn't read it).